# How Update Panel And Anthem hide method Name in client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I was using Update Panel,Anthem and jQuery in my projects.

I wonder how Update Panel and Anthem hide method name that should call in server side (like button click) but in jQuery we should specify server side method name.

How they do this?and why in jQuery we can't?

what is security issues may arise if any one know method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because UpdatePanel sends the entire page's view state back to the server and vice versa. You can examine that by using FireBug plugin or Fiddler. More info:[[+]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748441/regarding-updatepanel-internal)